# The value of '1033' in attribute 'language' on record of type 'webresource' not a provisioned LCID error on deploy

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Getting "The value of '1033' in attribute 'language' on record of type 'webresource' not a provisioned LCID error on deploy." error on deployment. Here is pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: base language of this CRM org?

Comment: What is it you're trying to deploy? Can you deploy it through the GUI?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Base language is Turkish.

Comment: So is US English language installed? (1033 is the LCID for English)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the English Language code `1033` is provisioned in your organization/environment pay pasting this query in your browser:

`https://YOUR_ORG.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/RetrieveAvailableLanguages`

If `1033` is not in the list of LCIDs in that returned payload, that means English is not provisioned in your organization. So to resolve your issue you you will need to:

1. Go to `http://aka.ms/ppac`
2. Select your environment
3. Go to Settings
4. Go to Product > Languages
5. Select the English language and install it